# Response.Redirect and thread was being aborted error?

Tags: asp.net, boolean, redirect, response.redirect

I had this error **Thread was being aborted.**, this afternoon in my error log.

The code that caused this error is:

```
Response.Redirect("Login.aspx", true);
```

If I change the `bool` value to `false`, the error log becomes empty and this error stops coming again, but the program stops working.

If I keep it as such, I am getting this error like nuisance.

I want to know the alternative for using `Response.Redirect` passing `true` as the value for the `endResponse` parameter.

Comment: Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Respose.Redirect will call Response.End internally , it can be suppressed by by using 'false' (Response.Redirect (Login.aspx, false);) .But it should not cause the program stop working though.

Comment: It can stop the program from working if other logic is being processed after the redirect that would otherwise not be processed if the exception had been raised.

Comment: @wizzard.. Its  working,but it does not allow to carry my session variable across the page.

Comment: @Thanks Mike. The site link is very useful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I catch this exception and swallow it because ASP.NET is using exceptions for flow control rather than for an exceptional circumstance.

```
try
{
    // Do stuff.
}
catch(ThreadAbortException)
{
    // Do nothing. ASP.NET is redirecting.
    // Always comment this so other developers know why the exception 
    // is being swallowed.
}
catch(OtherExceptionTypes ex)
{
    // Log other types of exception.
}
```

Comment: What will be printed in the error log if I use thread exception instead of ordinary exception ?

Comment: If you catch and swallow the exception then nothing, because no exception gets to the point where it gets logged. It also sounds like you need to read up on how exceptions work too.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt installed .net in my home system. So I was in a doubt.

Comment: What is the namespace for OtherExceptionTypes?

Comment: OtherExceptionTypes is not an actual type. It was just meant as a placeholder to indicate that you put a reference to another exception class there. If you want a catch all then use catch(Exception ex) { /* Do stuff */ } which will catch all other exception types that have not already been caught. Although, that is generally considered to be poor practice. If you have no reason to catch an exception then don't, just leave that clause out.

Comment: TIL you can attach more than one catch() onto a try block

Comment: +1 Thanks for this...was using Response.Redirect(<site>,false); to get out of this error but it obviously was processing everything else below...not ideal.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in `Response.Redirect(url)` ThreadAbortException Solution:

> The ThreadAbortException is thrown when you make a call to
>   `Response.Redirect(url)` because the system aborts processing of the
>   current web page thread after it sends the redirect to the response
>   stream. `Response.Redirect(url)` actually makes a call to `Response.End()`
>   internally, and it's `Response.End()` that calls `Thread.Abort()` which
>   bubbles up the stack to end the thread. Under rare circumstances the
>   call to `Response.End()` actually doesn't call `Thread.Abort()`, but
>   instead calls `HttpApplication.CompleteRequest()`.

Or simply move `Response.Redirect("~/Membership/UserRegistration.aspx");` out of the Try/Catch block.

Answer (score 2):

you can change like this 
Response.Redirect ("Login.aspx",false)
then it wont abort.

Answer (score 1):

For all caught errors where you want to redirect, create a 'GoTo' destined out of the Try Catch as follows:

```
    Try 

       'do stuff

    Catch ex As Exception

        'logging
        GoTo MyRedirection

    End Try

    'Prevent redirection in case of no errors
    Exit Sub

MyRedirection:
    Response.Redirect("login.aspx", True)
```

This neither causes thread abortion nor requires multiple catches.