# How to redirect htm page to another using Response.Redirect?

Tags: c#

I am trying to redirect my login.htm to index.htm in c#. both files are inside the folder named 'default'. after logging in, if the credential is correct, I want to redirect the login page to index. using the code below, but there is an exception message `Attempted to cancel thread.`. Is there a way to fix this?? How you can help me. Thanks in advance.

```
[WebMethod]
public void LogMeIn(string user, string pass) {
    try  {
        using (MySqlConnection dbConn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString())) {
            if (dbConn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) dbConn.Close();
            dbConn.Open();
            MySqlCommand sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbllogin WHERE userName = '" + user + "' AND passWord ='" + pass + "'", dbConn);
            int rowCount = (int)sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if (rowCount > 0) {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("../default/index.htm"); //redirect to new htm page
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)  {
        Console.WriteLine("Error Message : " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try the username `' or 1 = 1 or userName = '`

Comment: @John What my question is, How to redirect to a new page?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Response.Redirect and thread was being aborted error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368640/response-redirect-and-thread-was-being-aborted-error)

Comment: Your web site is **not** secure, you are open to a SQL Injection vulnerability

Comment: @bradbury9 , that wasn't my question sir. i will fix that after I finished the redirection problem

Comment: Do note that before warning about your SQL injection, I did link you another question with the same exact error and already answered/solved. Consider checking that answer.

Comment: @bradbury9 , Sorry Sir, did not notice that. Still, it returns an erorr, INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath+"default/index.htm");
```

Or you can use this way.

[HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect is trying to send users to the wrong place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980037/httpcontext-current-response-redirect-is-trying-to-send-users-to-the-wrong-place/5980070)

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/default/index.htm");
```

Comment: explain your answer also so user can understand

Comment: both did not work sir. the page wasn't redirected to another page.

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors and unnecesary code in your code example:

1. There is no need to check if `dbConn` is already opened, because it was just created
2. The `SELECT *` caused an Exception when doing later an `ExecuteScalar` because the table has more than one column. You should change it to `SELECT COUNT(*)`
3. Because how Microsoft handles how the flow of the page is done, if you don't end the response when doing the `Response.Redirect` you may need to catch an `ThreadAbortException`. To end the response you could check [Redirect(string url, bool endResponse) overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.redirect?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpResponse_Redirect_System_String_System_Boolean_)

That being said, you should do use parametrized queries, because unexpected or malicious input could cause you problems.

Comment: Hi Sir, I try your instructions to my code and the Internal Server Error wasn't there anymore, but the error now is `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)`